# How to use jQuery to get elements with the same z-index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Right now, I have elements with different `z-index`, and I want to group them using jQuery.

```
<div class="float" style="z-index:2"></div>
<div class="float" style="z-index:6"></div>
<div class="float" style="z-index:10"></div>
           .
           .
           .
<!-- You get the point -->
```

I can use `.attr("style")` to get the `z-index` value out, but it does not seem to be a good idea to do that. (and sometimes it might in the `<style>` tag too) Is there anything like that?

```
var ele = $("*[zindex=5]");
```

Looking forward for any solutions.

Comment: You can get the z-index with `.css('z-index')`, then sort them using plain JS.

Comment: @jimw - `$("*").css('z-index')` returns `"0"`.

Comment: Right, you have to apply `.css()` to each element to get its z-index.  Try something like `$('*').each(function() {console.log($(this).css('z-index'))});`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own custom selector:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
  zindex: function(el, i, m) {
    return $(el).css("z-index") === m[3];
  }
});
```

Which you could then use like this:

```
$("div:zindex(2)").each(function(){
 alert( this.innerHTML );
});
```

This will return all `div` elements with a `z-index` of `2`.

```
<div style="position:relative; z-index:2">Foo</div>
<div style="position:relative; z-index:6">Bar</div>
```

With the above markup, the earlier jQuery script will alert `Foo`.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/icevih/2/edit

Comment: `z-index` only works on elements that are *positioned*: http://jsfiddle.net/juDfe/3/

Answer (score 0):

If you add this function, then you will have them

```
$.fn.filterByZIndex = function(zIndex) {
    var $zElm = $("*").filter(function() {
        return $(this).css('z-index') == zIndex;
    });
    return $zElm;
};
```